# android sqlite getting distinct name and * amounts

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get a list of names with total amounts from a sqlite db.
It is working in a way that shows a list of all the transactions with the
correct combined total. I also have a table in the same db that has usernames
& phone numbers, but I don't think that would be too useful for this activity.
Also, how do I use the onListItemClick to send the next activity something
that I can use to pull only names from the User the person selected? The ID
is being sent, but I don't know how to use it.

ie:
trans table:
Justin    25
Justin    25
Justin    25
Sophia    80

Hoped results:
Justin    75
Sophia    80

Actual results:
Justin    75
Justin    75
Justin    75
Sophia    80

ListActivity that populates the list (with cursor and TextView link)

```
public class Totals extends ListActivity {
PaymentHelper helper;
Cursor model = null;
PaymentAdapter adapter = null;

UserHelper uhelp;
Cursor umodel = null;

public final static String ID_EXTRA = "com.curtis.bookkeeping._ID";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_person);

    helper = new PaymentHelper(this);
    model = helper.getAll();

    startManagingCursor(model);

    adapter = new PaymentAdapter(model);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    helper.close();
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Totals.this, Detail.class);
    i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
    startActivity(i);
}
public class PaymentAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    PaymentAdapter(Cursor c) {
        super(Totals.this, c, FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor c) {
        PaymentHolder holder = (PaymentHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_row, parent, false);

        PaymentHolder holder = new PaymentHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return row;
    }

}
static class PaymentHolder {

    private TextView name_line = null;
    private TextView amount_line = null;

    PaymentHolder(View row) {
        name_line = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name_row);
        amount_line = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.amount_row);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, PaymentHelper helper) {
        name_line.setText(helper.getName(c));
        amount_line.setText(Integer.toString(helper.sumPerson(c, helper.getName(c))));
    }
}
```

}

SQLiteOpenHelper code to retrieve info

```
public class PaymentHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bookkeeping.db";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public PaymentHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db1) {
    db = db1;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trans (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, date TEXT, amount INT, note TEXT)";
    //execute the sql statement
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void insert(String name, String date, int amount, String note){
    Log.e(name, date + " " + amount);
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("date", date);
    cv.put("amount", amount);
    cv.put("note", note);
    Log.e("Almost", "there");
    db.insert("trans", "abc", cv);
    Log.e("successfully", "inserted");
}
public Cursor getAll(){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM trans ORDER BY name";
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    return cursor;
}
public Cursor getAllNames(){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    return cursor;
}
public String getName(Cursor c){
    return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
}
public String getDate(Cursor c){
    return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date"));
}
public int getAmount(Cursor c){
    return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("amount"));
}
public String getNote(Cursor c){
    return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("note"));
}
public void delete(String id){
    String[] args = {id};
    getWritableDatabase().delete("trans", "_id=?", args);
}
public Cursor getById(String id){
    String[] args = {id};
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM trans WHERE _id=?";
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, args);
    return cursor;
}
public void update(String id, String name, String date, int amount, String note){
    String[] args = {id};
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("date", date);
    cv.put("amount", amount);
    cv.put("note", note);
    getWritableDatabase().update("trans", cv, "_ID=?", args);
}
public int sumPerson(Cursor c, String name){
    int total = 0;
    // add up totals
    String sql = "SELECT amount FROM trans WHERE name=?";
    String[] aname = new String[]{name};
    getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql,aname);
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        if(name.equals(getName(c))){
            total += c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("amount"));
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

}

This is the activity that is receiving the ID from Totals:
I would like it to show only one user (which they selected
from the totals page) with all of their transactions.

```
public class Detail extends ListActivity {
PaymentHelper helper;
Cursor model = null;
PaymentAdapter adapter = null;
public final static String ID_EXTRA = "com.curtis.bookkeeping._ID";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

    helper = new PaymentHelper(this);
    model = helper.getAll();
    startManagingCursor(model);

    adapter = new PaymentAdapter(model);
    setListAdapter(adapter);


}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    helper.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.details_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.totals:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Totals.class));
            break;
        case R.id.users:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Users.class));
            break;
        case R.id.home:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainMenu.class));
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Detail.this, DeletePayment.class);
    i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
    startActivity(i);
}

public class PaymentAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    PaymentAdapter(Cursor c) {
        super(Detail.this, c, FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor c) {
        PaymentHolder holder = (PaymentHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        PaymentHolder holder = new PaymentHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return row;
    }

}
static class PaymentHolder {

    private TextView name_line = null;
    private TextView date_line = null;
    private TextView amount_line = null;
    private TextView note_line = null;

    PaymentHolder(View row) {
        name_line = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name_line);
        amount_line = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.amount_line);
        date_line = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.date_line);
        note_line = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.note_line);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, PaymentHelper helper) {
        Log.e(helper.getName(c), Integer.toString(helper.getAmount(c)));
        name_line.setText(helper.getName(c));
        date_line.setText(helper.getDate(c));
        amount_line.setText(Integer.toString(helper.getAmount(c)));
        note_line.setText(helper.getNote(c));
    }
}
}
```

I know this is long...but help would be awesome!

I feel like the "PaymentAdapter" needs to be modified to only
read two names if there is only two names. Should I be utilizing 
the "UserHelper" db helper to populate this? but when I do, it only
runs one cursor through, and gets a nullpointerexception error because
it is not moving one of the cursors. Should I be making a PaymentAdapter
within PaymentAdapter to generate use of another cursor?

Comment: That's a lot of code... see if you can narrow your question down a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL query will give you the desired result:

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount)
FROM trans
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to SQL, how would I pull a number out of that?

Comment: Also, I think the problem is in the PaymentAdapter class, where it goes through the db and reads transactions instead of distinct names

Comment: You get a cursor with two columns (and the second column does not have a useful name; just use the column index to access it); you don't need the `sumPerson` function; just replace `getAll` with a function that does this query, and you can access both values directly in `populateFrom`.